# in apple app site association file, why "NOT" doesn't exclude path mentioned?

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have added universal links into my iOS application

```
messages http://somesite.com/message/list/ >> opens the app to messages 
review   http://somesite.com/review/add/   >> opens the app to review 
place    http://somesite.com/place/add/    >> opens the app to place 
photo    http://somesite.com/photo/add/    >> opens the app to photo
```

all working as expected, my question is : how to exclude paths or urls, in a way that it never even opens the app?

for example

```
somepage   http://somesite.com/somepagelink   >> SHOULDN'T OPEN APP, it must show up in the browser.
```

the apple app site association file

```
{
    "applinks": 
    {
        "details": [
        {
            "paths": ["*", "NOT /somepagelink/*"],
            "appID": "ID1.myApp"
        }, 
        {
            "paths": ["*", "NOT /somepagelink/*"],
            "appID": "ID2.myApp"
        }],
        "apps": []
    },
    "activitycontinuation": 
    {
        "apps": ["ID1.myApp","ID2.myApp"]
    }
}
```

is this the correct way to exclude a path?

```
"NOT /somepagelink/*"
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, your syntax is correct but:

The Apple documentation states, that the order of the statement is important.

> Because the system evaluates each path in the paths array in the order it is specified—and stops evaluating when a positive or negative match is found—you should specify high priority paths before low priority paths.

The first statement it evaluates in your file is the star "*" which signals "yes, every URL is allowed". Then it will end and open the app.

So maybe try it the other way round?

```
"paths": ["NOT /somepagelink/*", "*"],
```

**EDIT**

**IMPORTANT**:
This is from the comments given below, apart from changes in AASA.
You have to reinstall the app for every change to the apple-app-site-association file. It could definitely be a CDN problem if you are using one of those

Comment: the problem still is there, I excluded the path and it still clickable, i have removed the app and reinstalled, same same, the super weird thing is, when i make the whole apple-app-site-association empty, the app still opens the links normally, could it be the cdn ?

Comment: You have to reinstall the app for every change to the `apple-app-site-association` file. It could definitely be a CDN problem, if you are using one of those

Comment: this should be wiki :)

Comment: @AlexBauer should every user reinstall app or it takes some time to refresh?

Comment: I have the same issue as others in the comment. My `paths` array is just the following: `["NOT /subpath/negative/*", "/subpath/*"]`. All subpaths under `/subpath/negative/` are still opened in the app and I reinstalled the app, restarted the phone but this path is still matched.

Comment: @vinczemarton me too! Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @mesqueeb we messed about with it a lot and it seems the parsing is utterly broken, I will share it as a separate answer on how it finally worked

Answer (score 3):

It was not a CDN problem at our end. It turns out negative paths can be defined in multiple ways. Specifying them BOTH ways helped.

Let's say we have an app where:

- The main domain should **NOT** be opened under the app
- Everything *under* `/customer` should be opened in the app, except
- Everything *under* `/customer/not_included` should **NOT** be opened in the app

The final apple-app-site-association file is:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "[APPID]"
        ],
        "appID": "[APPID]",
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/customer/not_included/*",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "not_included exluded"
          },
          {
            "/": "/customer",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Customer exluded"
          },
          {
            "/": "/customer/",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Customer exluded"
          },
          {
            "/": "/customer/*",
            "comment": "Customer sub pages included"
          }
        ],
        "paths": [
          "NOT /customer/not_included/*",
          "NOT /customer",
          "NOT /customer/",
          "/customer/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "[APPID]"
    ]
  }
}
```

In your case the important part is that there are both `NOT` path and `exclude: true` components which look redundant but if we left out any of them the logic seem to have broken.